# How can I get NULL values returned in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have two dimensions named `T` and `L`

When I run this:

```
SELECT
  {measures.[value]} on 0,
  {nonempty([T].[Hierarchy Items].[T1])} on 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
  (
   [L].[L3].&[49733]
  )
```

I get all the T1 members and the where clause applies

But when I remove the `nonempty` function

```
SELECT
  {measures.[value]} on 0,
  {[T].[Hierarchy Items].[T1]} on 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
  (
   [L].[L3].&[49733]
  )
```

I will get all T1 members and the where clause does not apply.

Is there any way I get all null values also and the filter(where) applies too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how nonempty works. For example I want to see the InternetSalesAmount for 2011, consider the query below

```
select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0 ,
[Product].[Category].[Category]
on 1 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where 
[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2011]
```

Result:

[image]

Now the query return all products that were sold or not sold in 2011. For products that were sold it returns a sales amount. However the other three products were returned as a result of cartesian product between 2011 and product(MDX's where behavior is diffrent from SQL's where). Now I want to see only the products that were sold in 2011.

```
select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0 ,
nonempty(
[Product].[Category].[Category],
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) on 1 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where 
[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2011]
```

Result

[image]

For this purpose I can use {non empty} or {nonempty} keywords to tell MDX only to retrive those combinations which have a valid entry in the fact table. Since the fact table has no row for 2011 that has the other three products therefore it will not return them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there anyway I can get all the T1 members which the L3 = 49733 no matter if it is null or not?

Comment: @sqluser in your fact table you dont have a row for which L3 = 49733 and [T].[Hierarchy Items].[T1] and value is not null(). So you will not get a result. Run the following query(after adjustment as per enviroment) select * from yourFact where L3=49733 and HierarchyItem=T1, let me know if it returns any thing(If it does there is work around)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
WITH
SET S AS
EXISTS( 
  [T].[Hierarchy Items].[T1].members,
  { [L].[L3].&[49733] },
  "MeasureGroupName"
)
SELECT
  {measures.[value]} on 0,
  S on 1
FROM [Cube];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's returning everything.

Comment: @sqluser try adding a measure group third argument into the EXISTS function